# Specifying quotes within a preprocessor variable

Tags: wix

Is there an method for escaping double quotes in preprocessor variables?
I'm trying to define a variable to reduce redundancy but the quotes are giving me trouble.

```
<?define testCondition="(A="yes" AND B="no")"?>
```

I've not found any documentation and the following don't work

```
\",`","", &quot;
```

Comment: Did you try using &quot;

Comment: @Isaiah4110 Yep, that's listed above as one of the escape methods I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found what appears to be one of the more uglier workarounds, but seems to translate correctly.

```
<?define testCondition=""(A="yes" AND B="no")?>
<![CDATA[NOT $(var.testCondition)]]>
```

translates to

```
<![CDATA[NOT (A="yes" AND B="no")]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also came across similar issue. Here's what has worked for me:

```
<?define Prop_ParamsPrefix = ""["?>
<?define Prop_ParamsSufix  = "]""?>
```

Later inside shortcut I've used

```
...Arguments="/CONFIG $(var.Prop_ParamsPrefix)CONFIG_FILE$(var.Prop_ParamsSufix)"
```

In the end this is translated to:

```
/CONFIG "[CONFIG_FILE]"
```